# BLE registration

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

A question more on the legal side of electrical engineering:

We have designed and implemented an embedded sytem with a micro controller controlling a bluetooth module. The BT module has its own firmware and everything and we connect to it only using commands predefined by the manufacturer.

We have also implemented our own precedure to pair, sync data, and other commands and we never pay any attention to what GATT services or profiles we are using. Simply sending data via UART to BT module so that it transmits them to the app.

My question is now that we are going commercial, what kind of services and profiles should I register at BLE SIG?

Scanning the device, I see only on UUID for one service (along with device information: manufacturer name string, model number, etc.) which is a custom service.

Should this be registered so that we are allowed to use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a module that has already been qualified for Bluetooth, you would fall under [Path 1: Declaration Only](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/do-i-need-to-list-qualify-my-product) of the Qualification & Declaration Process.  This means that you still have to "declare" your product.

Comment: Thanks. even if we are developing the software on our own on the micro controller which controls the flow? We never changed the FW and boot-loader of the module itself.